# Rails ActiveStorage Versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a user model that allows each user to add images to their account. I am using ActiveStorage for upload. Can I allow a user to edit the image? Like draw on the picture and save it again

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable

  has_many_attached :images
```

Comment: The title says "versioning" but your question is about editting. Do you actually want versioning?

Comment: If you edit then save the file you have created a new version of the previous file